# Is there a way to determine Bitmap.getByteCount based on the image width, height and file size?

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, android-glide

Based on

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/RecordingCanvas.java

```
/** @hide */
private static int getPanelFrameSize() {
    final int DefaultSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB;
    return Math.max(SystemProperties.getInt("ro.hwui.max_texture_allocation_size", DefaultSize),
            DefaultSize);
}
/** @hide */
public static final int MAX_BITMAP_SIZE = getPanelFrameSize();

/** @hide */
@Override
protected void throwIfCannotDraw(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.throwIfCannotDraw(bitmap);
    int bitmapSize = bitmap.getByteCount();
    if (bitmapSize > MAX_BITMAP_SIZE) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Canvas: trying to draw too large(" + bitmapSize + "bytes) bitmap.");
    }
}
```

There is a hard limit 100MB `bitmap.getByteCount()` imposed on `ImageView`.

Is there any way we can figure out `bitmap.getByteCount()`, without perform I/O reading on image file itself.

This will help us to determine how we want to load the image into `ImageView`, without hitting the hard limit.

Currently, in our DB, we store the following meta data of the image file.

```
- Image file path
- Image type (PNG or JPG)
- Image file size in byte
- Image width
- Image height
```

Thanks.

Comment: you could just assume 24 or 32 bits per pixel and then calculate, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a really limit for ImageView Memory, but there is a limit for loaded/decoded Bitmap and it depends on Device/hardware. Usually it is "4096 x 4096 pixels x 4 (argb)" = near 70MB, but some device could have 8192x8192x4.

You can use this (pseudo code):

```
options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options)
final int H = options.outHeight;
final int W = options.outWidth;
```

then check its ColorSpace (ARGB or just RGB) and moltiply W x H x 3_or_4 to get Total bytes.